# Oracle SQL RDBMS tables data to mind map node structure

Tags: oracle, plot

I have done a lot of searching on this but not sure what my approach should be and looking for community advice. I would like to plot the graphical points of dependent data. The data already resides in a RDBMS and I have made some layered queries to plot the points and adapted to a node tree structure in Tableau. I have gotten to the second level, but it is quite convoluted and inefficient to continue down that path.

I am surprised a hierarchical db would be required for this. It's mostly algebraic logic.

Heres the concept:
Adapted from (and credence too) [Data + Science: Node-Link Tree Diagram in Tableau](http://www.dataplusscience.com/NodeLinkTreeDiagram.html)

[image]

I took this data and queried against a table with the t value. Then I applied the Sigmoid function in Tableau to create the connecting lines.

Here are my results so far.

Note the plot points are based off a 3rd level not shown which has 71 data points to it. This is why Level 1 y points are 36, 18, -18, 36. Level 2 is just plotted badly due to the algebra.

The goal is to get POSITION_1 & POSITION_2 to dynamically plot so that any changes in the tables automatically update the final result, ie. a living node-tree based off the RDBMS data.

Is my approach way off kilter, or is there a better way?

BTW, it's not to be blown to millions of nodes, just to probably 5 levels, somewhere in the hundreds.

[image]

Comment: Do you need a hierarchical query to generate the data?  For example, a query using a recursive common table expression, or the `connect by` syntax?

Comment: @JonHeller  I think that is exactly what I need, so long as I can decode the plot points from it. I tried reading up on it here: docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm but i could not get the query to work. An example from Table_1 and Table_2 would probably help me figure it out.

Comment: I mocked up the tables in fiddle http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4cd61/39

Comment: ...........................:(